# Sybase SUP,(2.1.3) using SAP RFC/BAPI, how to know when call results are available?

Tags: saprfc, sup

Scenario:

I am calling a SAP RFC from my MBO (as an OTHER).  The call makes updates to the database that I need to get back onto my device.  The call works correctly, eventually.  What mechanism can I use to let me know when the results are available?

1. Is there a consistent synchronous mechanism for (OTHER) calls?  Not my favorite, but ...
2. Do I have to poll in the background until I see my results?
3. Is there a callback that indicates that the device and server are in sync?
4. Apple notification messages?
5. Something else????

Thanks.

Comment: The answer may vary depending on what exactly you are updating - there's no general notification mechanism built into the backend. Perhaps you could let us know what you're trying to do in more detail?

Comment: It is an RFC that makes updates to the SAP system...  I can't guarantee how long it will take, but I don't want the user to busy wait.  I want to get the updates when they are available.